# Not able to redirect the output of grails run-app to a file while running it nohup

Tags: grails

As part of some automation script I require grails run-app to run in background and its output to be recorded/redirected to a log file.I am using below command to achieve the same , but right now not successful.

```
nohup /opt/grails-2.0.3/bin/grails -Ddisable.auto.recompile=true -Dserver.port=8080 run-app --non-interactive > consoleout.log 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

Any pointer would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command you've quoted works to pipe output to `consoleout.log`, but I assume your problem is that the output is repeated and garbled, e.g.:

```
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
```

You can fix this by adding the `--plain-output` parameter just after `--non-interactive`. This will cause Grails to output one line per message, without colour-coding, which works nicely for logs.

If your issue is with getting Grails to run using `nohup` and `&`, we'll need a little more information about what you're trying to achieve. If it's just running an instance of a Grails app on a server you probably want to generate a WAR file and run that inside a container such as Tomcat or Jetty rather than using `run-app`. You will also want to set the environment so it's not `development`.

[The Grails documentation on deployment](https://grails.org/Deployment) states that "Grails should never be deployed using the grails run-app command", but does provide guidance on deploying.

Comment: May be I am not getting anything in consoleout.log because I am running this command through chef recipe. The chef recipe snippet looks like this script "running grails" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "myuser"
  code <<-EOH
  source /etc/profile.d/java.sh
  source /etc/profile.d/grails.sh
  nohup /opt/grails-2.0.3/bin/grails -Ddisable.auto.recompile=true -Dserver.port=8080 run-app --non-interactive > consoleout.log 2>&1 > /dev/null &
  EOH
end . Any idea of how to run this through chef

Comment: It sounds like you're taking a very eclectic approach to deploying your application. You should use chef to check the application is installed, but it's far simpler to use RPM/DEB to install and manage dependencies, and standard UNIX init scripts to start/stop applications.